# How does SqlBulkCopy Work

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am familiar with the C# SqlBulkCopy class where you can call the 'WriteToServer' method passing through a DataTable.

My question is what underlying mechanism in SQL server is used to bulk insert that data?

The reason I ask is that the bulk insert referenced in the [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) MSDN T-SQL help file requires a data file to import. Does the SqlBulkCopy create a data file?

I would like to understand this stuff to work out whether I can use the bulk insert functionality in SQL.

If I write a SQL statement that prepares all the rows to insert into a particular table (thousands of rows) can I bulk insert them into the destination table? Something like this is how I am doing it now,

```
INSERT INTO sync_filters (table_name, device_id, road_id, contract_id)
    SELECT * FROM dbo.sync_contract_filters (@device_id)
```

And the dbo.sync_contract_filters is a function to generate all the rows to insert. Can this be bulk inserted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SqlBulkCopy does not create a data file. It streams the data table directly from the .Net DataTable object to the server using the available communication protocol (Named Pipes, TCP/IP, etc...) and insert the data to the destination table in bulk using the same technique used by BCP.

Comment: So kind of what I am interested in addition is can I create a SQL statement that will create the rows I need for a particular table, and then bulk insert them (this is completely using SQL). Can BCP do this for instance? I was under the impression that bcp uses tables too.

Comment: This interests me. Any idea how the datatable structure interacts with the ODBC connection in that wrapper? I'd like to build something similar with C++. Or are you aware of a c++ library that has a simular bulkcopy function? Maybe this can be done using a system() call to the BCP and avoid any custom programming to interact with the ODBC API?

Answer (score 9):

It took 7 years, but we finally have an answer...

Expounding upon Sam Anwar's answer, I can confirm it is converting the data to a raw byte stream and writing it to SQL as if it were streaming in from a file. *How* it tricks SQL into thinking it's reading a file is beyond me.

I wanted to do a bulk insert from inside a query, to speed up a slow clustered index insert. Upon finding your post here, somehow I became disturbingly intrigued, so I spent the past several hours studying it.

The execution path that actually writes data to the server seems to be:

Your Code:

1. Your code calls System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()

inside System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy:

2. which calls [WriteRowSourceToServerAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,54cddf315537c12c)()
3. which calls [WriteRowSourceToServerCommon](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,98b371f4e4cd3855)() to map the columns and [WriteToServerInternalAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,021747994517159e)() to write the data
4. which calls [WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,f45a7880167221b7)()
5. which calls [AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,e5fb9da82448b1d3)() *(This is the answer. Skip to step 14 to read about it.)* and [CopyBatchesAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,a2c3b79077a39bd0)()
6. which (CopyBatchesAsync) calls [SubmitBulkUpdateCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,e117e60d7c7f5552)()

-- inside System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser:

7. which calls System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.[TdsExecuteSQLBatch](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,a160614ab3bee307)()
8. which calls [WriteString](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,5737e2a7166d07d5)() or similar methods to convert the data into a byte array
9. which calls [WriteByteArray](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs,e4d2f6ab4fd506dc)()
10. which calls [WritePacket](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs,89a673f5325418aa)()
11. which calls [WriteSni](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs,fadf9910ccd522a9)()
12. which calls [SNIWritePacket](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParserStateObject.cs,f71ef034502cfa6a)()

-- inside System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper:

12. which calls [System.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIWritePacket](https://source.dot.net/#System.Data.SqlClient/Interop/SNINativeMethodWrapper.Windows.cs,1fea24d2e14b3b10)()
13. which *extern* calls [SNIWriteAsyncWrapper](https://source.dot.net/#System.Data.SqlClient/Interop/SNINativeMethodWrapper.Windows.cs,308526c44635a7fe)() or [SNIWriteSyncOverAsync](https://source.dot.net/#System.Data.SqlClient/Interop/SNINativeMethodWrapper.Windows.cs,b48f03083ebf5c87)()

Now here's where it gets tricky. I *think* this follows, but how I got there is a bit hacky. I opened the file properties on my copy of sni.dll, went to the details tab, and inside the Product Version property I found a reference to a "commit hash" of d0d5c7b49271cadb6d97de26d8e623e98abdc8db.

So I [googled that hash](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22d0d5c7b49271cadb6d97de26d8e623e98abdc8db), and via [this Nuget search](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=d0d5c7b49271cadb6d97de26d8e623e98abdc8db) I found [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win-x86.runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni/), whose title includes "System.Data.SqlClient.sni", which implies the namespace *System.Data.SqlClient.SNI*, which I found [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Data.SqlClient/System/Data/SqlClient/SNI/SNICommon.cs), but this doesn't have the right methods and doesn't actually seem to communicate with a server.

So this is where I ran out of know-how; this is as deep as I could get before it goes into native code I can't find anywhere. And although I'm not sure what all that other noise up above was...

14. Remember Step 4 ([WriteToServerInternalRestContinuedAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,f45a7880167221b7)()) also calls [AnalyzeTargetAndCreateUpdateBulkCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlBulkCopy.cs,e5fb9da82448b1d3)()
15. which concatenates a SQL query inside a StringBuilder named updateBulkCommandText. Line 544 in that last link.

TLDR: Ultimately it appears it just executes an *[INSERT BULK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)* query (which does not require a file), and does not actually use *[BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)* (which does). Note these two commands look very similar.

An important note in the Microsoft docs:

> Used by external tools to upload a binary data stream. This option is
> not intended for use with tools such as SQL Server Management Studio,
> SQLCMD, OSQL, or data access application programming interfaces such
> as SQL Server Native Client.

Which I interpret as "use at your own risk and don't expect help".  Which is almost as good as a green light, in all fairness.

Comment: Some interesting links https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d9bf8677-7138-457a-afae-948ae749465e/what-is-insert-bulk?forum=transactsql#answers https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36604/insert-bulk-in-sql-profiler-without-values https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186269/how-do-i-capture-the-data-passed-in-sqlbulkcopy-using-the-sql-profiler/35562149#35562149

Comment: Indeed, thanks.  Here's another interesting link; some rando's best effort to document the raw TDS format. https://www.freetds.org/tds.html

Answer (score 2):

SqlBulkCopy can use a datatable, IDataReader or DataRow[] as a datasource. Take a look at the WriteToServer methods of the class. I've found it to be quite a useful mechanism of getting data into SQL Server. I've used this in conjunction with [CSVReader](http://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/upload_csv.php) previously. The previous link gives you an idea of how it works with a class that implements IDataReader.

You might need to [play around with the batch sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779690/what-is-the-recommended-batch-size-for-sqlbulkcopy) to ensure you get the performance you are expecting.

[The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) on MSDN is quite a useful resource if you are looking at getting the best performance out of writing large amounts of data quickly. It focuses more on things like BCP and BULK INSERT, but touches on SQLBulkCopy and also provides quite a lot of food for thought (maybe a little too much, but it is a useful reference at least anyway).