# c# SqlBulkCopy - hot to get the raw sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am using the c# and SqlBulkCopy to insert some records at once to my db.
the records list is small up to a 100-200 records.

here is my code:

```
 using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;

                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
```

I have a time out exception from time to time and I would like to get the raw sql query in order to investigate some more.
can anybody tell me how do I pull that out of the SqlBulkCopy object?

Comment: Finaly close the reader.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [**BulkCopyTimeout**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.bulkcopytimeout.aspx) property. I think by default your connection timeout is used.

I don't think you can get the SQL out of BulkCopy as I don't it's doing regular INSERTs.
You could try to run SQL Profiler.

If you want to generate INSERT statements for inserting existing data (so you can run it on a different database) you could use [**SQL Data Compare**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) from Red Gate. I think they have a free version available.

Comment: would be interesting to see if you do actually get anything from SQL profiler. The doc's don't really say what it does under the hood.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12189324/542251) seems to *imply* that you won't get anything in profiler, hardly definitive though.

Comment: this is what I saw in sql proiler:
insert bulk destinationTableName ([colAName] BigInt, [colBName] NVarChar(250) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS)

Comment: @Gidi - Yes, that's what you will get in Profiler.