# Transfer huge dataframe to SQL Server table

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to bulk copy a DF with 1.5B rows into a SQL Server table.  It's just 5 columns, but the number of rows is massive.  I'm trying this method.

```
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.bulkcopy.BulkCopyMetadata
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

val bulkCopyConfig = Config(Map(
  "url"               -> "mysqlserver.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName"      -> "MyDatabase",
  "user"              -> "username",
  "password"          -> "*********",
  "dbTable"           -> "dbo.Clients",
  "bulkCopyBatchSize" -> "100000",
  "bulkCopyTableLock" -> "true",
  "bulkCopyTimeout"   -> "600"
))

df.bulkCopyToSqlDB(bulkCopyConfig)
```

I'm following the example from the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector

It keeps running and running, for hours, but never copies anything from the DF to the table.  Thoughts?  Suggestions?  Thanks.

BTW, if I try to copy a much smaller DF, with around 1.5M rows, it works just fine.

Comment: Does the transactions complete or do you cancel it? Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: suggest you look at sys.dm_exec_requests while doing the import to see what is happening.  Alternatively, you can start an XE or profiler session and watch the commands completing to get a sense of what is happening.

Comment: Install `whoisactive` on the destination database and see what's going on. https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive

Comment: What kind of indexes are you using on target table? Rowstore/Columnstore/Clustered Columnstore/Heap?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, I think your issue was caused by the value of `bulkCopyBatchSize` parameter, as the offical document [Managing Bulk Copy Batch Sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-bulk-copy-operations/managing-bulk-copy-batch-sizes?view=sql-server-ver15) said as below, but not the larger batch size, the better performance.

> The number of rows making up a batch can have significant performance effects when bulk copying a large number of rows. The recommendations for batch size depend on the type of bulk copy being performed.
>
> - ***When bulk copying to SQL Server, specify the TABLOCK bulk copy hint and set a large batch size.***
> - When TABLOCK is not specified, limit batch sizes to less than 1,000 rows.

As reference, please see the answer of the SO thread [What is the recommended batch size for SqlBulkCopy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779690/what-is-the-recommended-batch-size-for-sqlbulkcopy) to set a `5000` value for `bulkCopyBatchSize` parameter to try again. I think it will get better performance than your current one, because more batch size will cost more time to send the network packets (include more retry packets) in a batch to wait for a successful response.

Comment: this has a scala limitation. Any idea on pythonic way of achieving this ?